# JasperReport using iReport not support unicode character while export to pdf format

Tags: unicode, jasper-reports, report

I am using iRport design tool to create the report in my project. I have created .jrxml and .jasper file, it works fine in the iReport means it supports for the Unicode character and displaying all unicode characters but if I integrated this .jasper file in my java class and exports the report into the pdf format by using itext jar file. Then the program runs well and create the report in pdf format but not showing the unicode characters in the generated report file. So please help me in this case sothat I will able to view unicode characters in the generated report file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the [`JasperReports`](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) has the *`unicode`* support.

This articles are about *`unicode`* support:

- [JasperReports - Unicode Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/unicode/index.html)
- [JasperReports - Fonts Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions)

The main concept is to use the ***`Font Extensions`*** mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I think, You may need to add uni code font to class path.